# Where is the right place of the 的 in this sentence

Tags: usage

I am not sure where I have to put the 的 in this sentence, if someone could explain me

我的西班牙语只学了半年 
or 
我只学了半年的西班牙语

Comment: Both sentences are OK, except that you omitted a "了“ in the first sentence, which should be 我的西班牙语只学了半年.

Comment: thx a lot, I added the 了 because it was not the topic of my question, could you explain me what are the differences between these two sentences, and which is the most used please

Comment: The difference is that the subject is 我的西班牙语 in the first sentence and 我 in the second one.

Comment: Yes, both are ok. But not sure @ltux comment about the subject of the first sentence. I think the subject of the first sentence is still "I". It just moved the object 西班牙语 to before the verb. Spanish language can't learn, only I can learn. "I Spanish learned" or "I learned Spanish". You can omit 的 in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

> *我的西班牙语只学了半年 or 我只学了半年的西班牙语*

**我的**= **my** (the 的 after 我 denote possessive)

半年**的** = half year **of** (the 的 after 半年 is an adjectival suffix that turn 半年 into a relative phrase of 学~西班牙语 )

Comment: is it correct to use 我的西班牙语 as subject in this sentences?
Could you send me a link that explain, I study or my spanish studies are both ok to use.  It hard to me to understand something can study.

Comment: 「我的西班牙語 (my Spanish) 」in 「我的西班牙語祇學了半年 」 is the object, not the subject. The subject 「我 ( I ) 」 is omitted. in Chinese, it is preferable to omit the subject  whenever possible. If we don't omit the subject, the sentence would be 「我的西班牙語，(我)祇學了半年」. Then我 would appear in the same sentence twice. Since omitting the subject doesn't effect the coherence of the sentence,  the second 我 (subject - " I ") should be omitted.